# Making multiple SSL requests fast in Python 2.x

Tags: python, performance, ssl, https

I have a Python program that has to do a lot of HTTPS communication with a third-party server on the other side of the world.

Every time the program wants to communicate with that server, it starts a new HTTPS request.

I came to understand that this is very inefficient, because then the SSL handshake needs to be made every single time, which is taking up a lot of roundtrips, which are very expensive because of how far away we are from the server.

Is there a way to make subsequent HTTPS requests fast after the first one was made? (I don't know much about SSL, and I don't know whether this means keeping connections alive, or any other thing.)

(One thing I saw that could have helped is [`ssl.SSLContext`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html#ssl-contexts), but it's only available in Python 3.2, while we're working with Python 2.7.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics, but two thoughts come to mind:

1) You could just do each connection on a different processor, in parallel, using multiprocessing or even multithreading.  So the SSL handshakes are still slow, but it doesn't matter as much because they're done in parallel.

2) You could try to ensure you're using HTTP/1.1 and not HTTP/1.0; supposedly the latter allows reusing connections.